# Select N random rows from a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 3D array that I want to take random 'sets' (note: not a pythonic set) from axis 1, N times. I can achieve this via nested For loops, but I will need to do this at least 10000 times, so I need to find a vectorised solution if possible.

I will try to explain this using an example. If I want to retrieve N sets of data, I want to select one random index from axis 1 in my 3D array, for every element in axis 0. E.g. In the first of my N sets I randomly select indices `[0, 2, 1]`, this correlates to the three different array positions: `[0, 0, :]`, `[1, 2, :]`, and `[2, 1, :]`, respectively (i.e. axis 0 increments by one each time, and axis 1 is based on the randomly selected indices).

Below is a numerical example in pseudo-code:

```
# Create some arbitrary data (EDIT: based on mozway's answer)
a = array([[[ 0. ,  4. ,  8. , 12. , 16. , 20. , 24. ],
            [ 1. ,  5. ,  9. , 13. , 17. , 21. , 25. ],
            [ 2. ,  6. , 10. , 14. , 18. , 22. , 26. ],
            [ 3. ,  7. , 11. , 15. , 19. , 23. , 27. ]],

           [[ 0.1,  4.1,  8.1, 12.1, 16.1, 20.1, 24.1],
            [ 1.1,  5.1,  9.1, 13.1, 17.1, 21.1, 25.1],
            [ 2.1,  6.1, 10.1, 14.1, 18.1, 22.1, 26.1],
            [ 3.1,  7.1, 11.1, 15.1, 19.1, 23.1, 27.1]],

           [[ 0.2,  4.2,  8.2, 12.2, 16.2, 20.2, 24.2],
            [ 1.2,  5.2,  9.2, 13.2, 17.2, 21.2, 25.2],
            [ 2.2,  6.2, 10.2, 14.2, 18.2, 22.2, 26.2],
            [ 3.2,  7.2, 11.2, 15.2, 19.2, 23.2, 27.2]]])


# Define the number of requested sets
N = 2

# Define the chosen data per 'set' (normally would be random)
idx = [[0, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3]]

# First set would give (with choices [0, 2, 1]):
arr = [[ 0. ,  4. , 8.  , 12. , 16. , 20. , 24. ],
       [ 2.1,  6.1, 10.1, 14.1, 18.1, 22.1, 26.1],
       [ 1.2,  5.2, 9.2 , 13.2, 17.2, 21.2, 25.2]]

# Second set would give (with choices [1, 3, 3]):
arr = [[ 1. ,  5. ,  9. , 13. , 17. , 21. , 25. ],
       [ 3.1,  7.1, 11.1, 15.1, 19.1, 23.1, 27.1],
       [ 3.2,  7.2, 11.2, 15.2, 19.2, 23.2, 27.2]]

# So, the final output would combine all sets:
arr = [[[ 0. ,  4. , 8.  , 12. , 16. , 20. , 24. ],
        [ 2.1,  6.1, 10.1, 14.1, 18.1, 22.1, 26.1],
        [ 1.2,  5.2, 9.2 , 13.2, 17.2, 21.2, 25.2]],

        [ 1. ,  5. ,  9. , 13. , 17. , 21. , 25. ],
        [ 3.1,  7.1, 11.1, 15.1, 19.1, 23.1, 27.1],
        [ 3.2,  7.2, 11.2, 15.2, 19.2, 23.2, 27.2]]]
```

Comment: Can you explain your goal without the notion of loop? For example, starting from `x`, how do you chose the elements to yield the final output?

Comment: @mozway Based on my example, when first going through the loop, the goal is to collect 3 pieces of data, where each piece comes from a separate set of 4 'spectra', i.e. One piece is randomly chosen from the first 'row': [1, 2, ...,  7], [2, 3, ...,  8], [3, 4, ...,  9], [4, 5, ..., 10], the next piece from the second row: [1, 2, ..., 33], [2, 3, ..., 34], [3, 4, ..., 35], [4, 5, ..., 36], and the final piece from the third row: [1, 2, ..., 37], [2, 3, ..., 38], [3, 4, ..., 39], [4, 5, ..., 40]. These three randomly chosen 'spectra' form the first entry of 'temps'. This is repeated N times.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clean it to the minimal (i.e., explaining that you want to select random rows in axis1 but independently relative to axis0), you could remove all the code to just leave the description and input/output example

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I'll edit it in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the clarifications of your question, you want to select N random rows in a 3D array on axis 1 (second dimension), but independently on axis 0:

Let's call a the array and x,y,z its 3 dimensions.

An easy way is to select N*x random indices so that there is N per x. Then flatten the array on the first 2 dimensions and slice.

Example input (note the x/x.1/x.2 to track the originating dimension):

```
array([[[ 0. ,  4. ,  8. , 12. , 16. , 20. , 24. ],
        [ 1. ,  5. ,  9. , 13. , 17. , 21. , 25. ],
        [ 2. ,  6. , 10. , 14. , 18. , 22. , 26. ],
        [ 3. ,  7. , 11. , 15. , 19. , 23. , 27. ]],

       [[ 0.1,  4.1,  8.1, 12.1, 16.1, 20.1, 24.1],
        [ 1.1,  5.1,  9.1, 13.1, 17.1, 21.1, 25.1],
        [ 2.1,  6.1, 10.1, 14.1, 18.1, 22.1, 26.1],
        [ 3.1,  7.1, 11.1, 15.1, 19.1, 23.1, 27.1]],

       [[ 0.2,  4.2,  8.2, 12.2, 16.2, 20.2, 24.2],
        [ 1.2,  5.2,  9.2, 13.2, 17.2, 21.2, 25.2],
        [ 2.2,  6.2, 10.2, 14.2, 18.2, 22.2, 26.2],
        [ 3.2,  7.2, 11.2, 15.2, 19.2, 23.2, 27.2]]])
```

Processing:

```
N = 2
# sample with repeats
idx = np.random.randint(y, size=N*x)
corr = np.repeat(np.arange(0,(x-1)*y+1, y), N)
idx += corr
# sample without repeats
idx = np.concatenate([np.random.choice(list(range(y)), replace=False, size=N)+(i*y) for i in range(x)])
# slice array
a.reshape(x*y,z)[idx].reshape(x,N,z).swapaxes(0,1)
```

possible output (N,x,z) shape:

```
array([[[ 0. ,  4. ,  8. , 12. , 16. , 20. , 24. ],
        [ 1.1,  5.1,  9.1, 13.1, 17.1, 21.1, 25.1],
        [ 0.2,  4.2,  8.2, 12.2, 16.2, 20.2, 24.2]],

       [[ 3. ,  7. , 11. , 15. , 19. , 23. , 27. ],
        [ 3.1,  7.1, 11.1, 15.1, 19.1, 23.1, 27.1],
        [ 1.2,  5.2,  9.2, 13.2, 17.2, 21.2, 25.2]]])
```

Comment: I realize I forgot to add `.reshape(x,N,z).swapaxes(0,1)` at the end to get the (N,x,z) shape

Answer (score 1):

##### Original answer  before the question was clarified, see [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69584120/16343464) for a independent sampling

You can get random indices and slice:

```
N = 2

# get random indices on the first dimension
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(x.shape[0]), size=N)

# slice
x[idx]
```

example output (shape: (2, 3, 7)):

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  5, 10, 17, 26, 37],
        [ 2,  3,  6, 11, 18, 27, 38],
        [ 3,  4,  7, 12, 19, 28, 39],
        [ 4,  5,  8, 13, 20, 29, 40]],

       [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]]])
```

Example on other dimensions:

```
# second dimension (axis 1)
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(x.shape[1]), size=N)
x[:, idx]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned in my comment to @warped, I have made an edit to try to further explain my question!

Comment: @AlexP I'll read you update when I have a moment, but have you seen at the bottom of my answer that I provided a solution for the second dimension (axis 1)

Comment: Thank you in advance. Yes, I did see your second dimension (axis 1) example, however it also is not what I am after. Hopefully my edits clear it up (again, sorry for the confusion!), but to point out why your solution doesn't work for me:

The second dimension example you gave produces a (3, N, 7) array, where each of the three sets (axis 0) of N data is taken from their respective first axis 0 equivalents in 'x'.

What I want is an (N, 3, 7) array, where each set of data along axis 0 is 3 'samples', one randomly taken from each of the 4 'spectra' sets of axis 0.

Comment: @AlexP I see, that's no problem. I provided [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69584120/16343464) for clarity